# Required a bean of type 'com.me.app.vo.MyClassVO ' that could not be found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, autowired, dto

I have a POJO class used as ValueObject class to show the DAO values to the screen. In my service class I have autowired the class object. I am getting below error when I start my application. Service class is annotated with @Service not sure What is missing in my VO class. Should I annotate it with @bean or anything else ?

```
Parameter 5 of constructor in com.me.app.service.MyServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.me.app.vo.MyClassVO' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
```

Names of the class is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide any code but I assume that you have a parameter of type `MyClassVO` in the constructor of `MyServiceImpl`

Therefore Spring tries to inject a bean of type `MyClassVO`. But I assume that `MyClassVO` is not a Spring Bean.

So you have two options:

1. Remove the MyClassVO if it shouldn't be a Spring Bean
2. Make `MyClassVO` a Spring Bean by annotating it with `@Component`

As VO is usually the abbreviation of Value Object I assume that the option 1 would be the better solution.

Comment: VO is similar to DTO. A screen mapper Class for a particular Entity class.

Comment: I assume that you have a parameter of type MyClassVO in the constructor of MyServiceImpl -  Yes added.

Comment: A DTO class can be a spring bean rt ?

Comment: It can but it shouldn't be. So in your case you shouldn't have the DTO as parameter in the constructor. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: So how to initialize the DTO Object in the service class ? using new operator ?

Comment: Yes sure! Spring Beans are by default Singeltons and are managed objects. DTOs are instantiated by the application.

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation. I am marking it as Answer.

Comment: I'm happy to help